# Finding and deleting duplicated records

Tags: linux, sed, grep

I want to find the duplicated record in which same characters are duplicated For example, the pattern that I want to find is 'AA' or 'AAAAA' I try to use the grep command to find it. But it doesn't work well Here is the example that I tried, ATCTAGCGATCGATAGCTAGCTAGCTAGCTAGCTAGCTAGCTAGCTAGCTAGCTAGCTAGCTAGCTAGCTAGCTAGCTAGCTAGCTAGCTAGCTAG TATCTATCTATCTATCTCATACTTCGCATCGCTAGCTCGACTGCATAGGACTAGCATAAAAAGCATCAGCTACCGCCTCAGCATCGACTACGATACG TAGTCGATCGACAGCTACGCATGCATCCGACTACGATCGACTAGCTAGCGCTAGACTACGTACCGATAAGCACTACGTCAGCCTAGACTCACGACT GATCGATCGATCGACTACGCAGCTACGAGATCGATCGATCGATCGTAGCTAGCTCATACTACACACGCATATACGTGTCGATgctAGTAACTACAT ACGCTAGCTAGCTACGATCAATCGAGCTATCGATCAGCTACGATCTAGAGATCGATCGATGCTGATAGCTACGATCagcactgatGCATCGCTGAT

Comment: It is unclear what you want to do (or what you say you tried). Are you looking for single lines in which `AA` or `AAAAA` is repeated multiple times?  Since this looks like genomic data, are you also wanting to look for matches across line breaks? What is "a record" and what do you mean by "duplicated record"?

Comment: As you understand, the duplicated records means pattern in which the same nucleic acid appears repeatedly

Comment: Yes, but you also say "duplicated record in which same characters are duplicated". So I can see that `A` is repeated in `AAAAA`.  Is `A` a "record" or is `AAAAA` a record? If `AAAAA` is a record, what is meant by "duplicate record"? Is that multiple instances of `AAAAA`? It's futher unclear what you want to do with these strings once you have found them. Consider updating your question with some data showing the state before the operation and after.  Also mention whether you want to match across line breaks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is somewhat unclear. Assuming you want to find all substrings comprised of same nucleic acid 2 or more times, sed can help:

```
sed -r 's:([ACGTacgt])\1+:\n>&\n:g;s:^[^>]+$::mg;s:\n+>?:\n:g' INPUT
```

**Output:**

```
TT
GG
AAAAA
CC
CC
CC
CC
AA
CC
AA
AA
```

For a specific nucleic acid, use for example `[Aa]` instead, at the start of the script.